# vert.x mySQL Javascript driver library

Tags: javascript, mysql, vert.x

I just discovered vert.x and am very intrigued by it.  The first thing I do when I discover a new framework is seek out a mySQL driver.  I've searched all over and it seems there is nothing available.  How would one go about developing such a library?

Comment: haven't delved into vert.x yet, but by the looks of what I've read so far they're currently only supporting No-SQL DBs?
The tutorials I've read only seem to speak of MongoDB right now.

Answer (score 1):

vert.x is agnostic as to which data source you use. You can just instantiate and use the standard MySQL JDBC driver in your Verticle.

Comment: Isn't JDBC for Java, not JavaScript?

Comment: You can use Java stuff inside Javascript, via Rhino. That's how vert.x works too...

Answer (score 1):

Here is the thing. You DON'T need a javascript driver.

As vert.x is using rhino to compile javascript into java class. So what you actually need is the native java driver for mysql, and use rhino's [java scripting](http://www.mozilla.org/rhino/ScriptingJava.html) features to access it.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that current JDBC drivers don't support the concurrency model and the asynchrones nature of vert.x.  One would have to write a brand new JDBC driver for each DB vendor to support it.  Not a light undertaking.

Comment: or https://github.com/timyates/mod-jdbc-persistor/ might be a way round this till we get asynchronous jdbc drivers